# Word won't save when box is copied

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA program that automates assembly of Word documents from other docs using mostly copy/pasting and bookmark insertions. One template won't save after copying from another document.  Here is the code that errors:

```
'get starting doc w macro (styletemplate)
Set mydoc = wrd.Documents.Open(strformattemplate, False, False) 
'this is the base doc with styles - this save works fine 
mydoc.SaveAs2 filename:=strNewName,FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled

'here's our skeleton  this is what we want to copy in
Set skel = wrd.Documents.Open(skelpath)
Set rangetocopy = skel.Range(0, skel.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").End)
rangetocopy.copy ' copy to clipboard
'copy in the skeleton and close it
Set workingrange = mydoc.Range(0, mydoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").End)
workingrange.Paste
mydoc.Save  'here's where it's failing
skel.Close False
```

The second save fails. There is an endless pop-up. The user must abort.  I want to emphasize that this code works on all other templates. It appears to fail if one shape (a box that is an underline for a header) is included. Boxes like this appear in the first page of each chapter.

Comment: Whats the pop up you refer to say?

Comment: The popup is just the Save As dialog. I tried saving it as another name, but it pops up in an endless loop.